# Inverse of Tan in python (tan-1)

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I am trying to calculate the inverse of tan in python, but it does not give me the correct value, for example, if I were to do the inverse tan of 1.18, `math.atan(1.18)`

```
>>>math.atan(1.18)
0.8677
```

However, the correct answer is 49.720136931. What is the correct way to do than?

Comment: How do you figure to get 49 radians in a circle?

Comment: radians, degrees...

Comment: The correct answer is 49.720136931 *apples*.

Comment: @calocedrus Now I understand why my teacher would blast me for not providing in what I measured.

Answer (score 129):

[`math.atan(x)`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.atan) returned in radian, if you want degree, convert it using [`math.degrees(x)`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.degrees)

```
Converts angle x from radians to degrees.

>>> import math
>>> math.degrees(math.atan(1.18))
49.720136931043555
```

Answer (score 10):

you can simply multiply the radians by 180/pi.
No need of importing ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
>>>from math import *
>>>degrees(atan(1.18))
>>>49.720136931043555
```

Answer (score 0):

similar answer for pandas/numpy series:

```
np.degrees(np.arctan(df['column']))
```